# Not receiving emails (no bounced errors) but can send out emails - Postfix, Dovecot, Webmin/Virtualmin

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, webmin, virtualmin

I'm using CentOS with Postfix, Dovecot, Webmin/Virtualmin. I can't seem to receive emails for all addresses for one of our virtual servers configured via Webmin/Virtualmin. But I can send out (and it was received).

I tested sending using 3 Gmail addresses as senders and also a private email. No bounced email or errors whatsoever. I tried checking using POP3 and Usermin webmail and both do not receive the emails.

I also checked var/log/maillog and there's no error correlating to this issue. I also restarted Postfix, Dovecot.

Both SPF and SKIM passed as tested.

I also troubleshooted the following and it was fine (not real IP or domain).

```
[root@server ~]# host -t mx mysite.com
mysite.com mail is handled by 5 mail.mysite.com.
[root@server ~]# host mail.mysite.com
mail.mysite.com has address 103.230.54.115
[root@server ~]# host 103.230.54.115
115.54.230.103.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer server.mysite.com.
```

UPDATE: I just realized that I could receive the emails to my server from Gmail website, NOT from POP3 Gmail (from my Outlook).

Comment: Does the Postfix log have _any_ mentions of your incoming mail at all? (At the very minimum, an incoming SMTP connection from Gmail systems?) Have you checked with your SMTP server's hosting company?

Comment: (Also, for the record, the IP address 103.230.54.115 would have its rDNS at 115.54.230.103.in-addr.arpa, not at 103.230.54.115.in-addr.arpa... Please don't go overboard when faking command output.)

Comment: @user1686 Funny thing is no. No mention. I'm hosting my own EC2 server at AWS. I'm sending the email from Gmail. So SMTP is Gmail.

Comment: By "your SMTP server" I mean the one that you're running Postfix on. (Gmail acts as SMTP client when delivering.) If it's AWS, have you checked security groups?

Comment: @user1686 I just realized that I could receive the emails to my server from Gmail website, NOT from POP3 Gmail (from my Outlook).

Comment: @user1686 You said "Have you checked with your SMTP server's hosting company?" What should I check? The maillog doesn't say anything about an incoming SMTP connection from Gmail systems. It only says lots of "SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure"..." disconnect from unknown[87.246.7.70]"